# How to give permission for recycle application pool in iis 7(without providing admin credentials) using c#

Tags: c#, iis-7, directoryservices

```
string app_Path = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/Application pool name";
DirectoryEntry app_pool = new DirectoryEntry(app_Path);
app_pool.Invoke("Recycle");
```

I'm using above code and I'm getting rid of this particular thing where I cannot recycle the application pool in IIS7 through c# whilst I'm running this code through web server.

This gets strucks when it comes to the invoke method because of permission issue and throwing this below exception.

```
     Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

how to come out of this and how can i give permission without admin credentials.And also i tried in web config file by giving impersonate is true for identity tag but no use.How to fix it and what is the solution?

Thanks,

Harish Jay

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to solve the *problem* for which the "solution" is to recycle the app pool?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:Due to some reasons that problem cannot be touched as of now.. So,only alternative way is to recycle app pool..Is der any way?